# php mail $body html template, hiding&showing depending from checkbox value

Tags: forms, templates, php

I have piece of php mail template which is optional and some users fills additional info, some are not, but if some don't fills it, template goes by email empty with not info from form.

```
$body = ''
```

here is part which always fillable by user:

```
<span>urgent info 01:</span> '.$urgent001.'<br />
<span>urgent info 02:</span> '.$urgent002.'<br />
```

and there are two fields which are optionsl and user can not fill those fields, however i'm getting:

> additional info01:
>
> additional info02:

Is there a chance to hide from template this part

```
<span>additional info 01:</span> '.$additional001.'<br />
<span>additional info 02:</span> '.$additional002.'<br />
```

if input is empty?

Thank you!